# Prestashop: How translate "Featured Products"?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

**Module:** `Ortho Theme Featured products`

**File:** 
`modules/otfeaturedproducts/views/templates/hook/otfeaturedproducts.tpl`

**Code:**

```html
<h1 class="main-title">
    {l s='Featured Products' d='Modules.Featuredproducts.Shop'}
</h1>
```

**I tried with the option:**

Translations ->International

[image]

After click in Modify only showed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved it. 2 errors found:

**1. The module:** Is Featured products

[image]

**2. The word:** is "Featured products" ("products" in lower case).

```
<h1 class="main-title">
    {l s='Featured products' d='Modules.Featuredproducts.Shop'}
</h1p
```